# elastic search parsing_exception for boost query

Tags: parsing, exception, elasticsearch

I'm trying to boost up the query using elastic search. Headlines that are published recently must be boosted up and should come on top. However, I have return the following code:

```
{
"query": {
"function_score": {
"query": {
    "bool": {
            "must": {
                  "match": { 
                       "keywords": {
                          "query":"trump"
                                       }
                                  }
                             },
       "should": [
           { "match": {
                     "type": {
                             "query": "headline"
               }
           }}
       ]}},  

    "functions": [
        { "boost":  5 },
        {
        "gauss": {
        "versioncreated": {
        "origin": "now/d", 
        "scale": "50w", 
        "offset": "4w", 
        "decay": "0.5" 
}}}],
        "score_mode": "sum"
}
}}
```

I'm getting this error :-

```
{
   "error": {
      "root_cause": [
     {
        "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "no [score_function] registered for [params]",
        "line": 24,
        "col": 20
     }
      ],
      "type": "parsing_exception",
      "reason": "no [score_function] registered for [params]",
      "line": 24,
      "col": 20
   },
   "status": 400
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You query is a bit wrong. What do you want do by this?

```
"functions": [
        { "boost":  5 },
```

If you want to boost it try to use this query

```
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": {
                        "match": {
                            "keywords": {
                                "query": "trump"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "should": [
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "type": {
                                    "query": "headline"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "functions": [
                {
                    "gauss": {
                        "versioncreated": {
                            "origin": "now/d",
                            "scale": "50w",
                            "offset": "4w",
                            "decay": "0.5"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "boost": 5,
            "score_mode": "sum"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it will boost the _score by 5
_score + 5 for each headline result